# WP7 Restsharp POST result null

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, restsharp

im trying to get RestShap working, but no luck so far. I havent really found any good documentation?

anyway, Should this work.. response.content is blank

```
 private void webclienttest()
   {
       string query = @"<?xml blah blah...>;
       var client = new RestClient("http://myurl.com");
       var request = new RestRequest(query, Method.POST);

       client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
       {
           var resource = response.Content;
           PopulateList();
       });

   }
```

Comment: Can you execute this same query using Fiddler, and does it work there?

Comment: A couple issues: the first param in the restrequest ctor is the resource URL off the base of the client baseurl.  Secondly theres a variety of ways to set the request body. What I'd suggest is posting the desired raw http request needed to http://groups.google.com/group/restsharp

Comment: Turned out it was the same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987557/wp7-httpwebrequest-exception-on-nodo-but-not-mango

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
client.ExecuteAsync (request, response =>
        {
            RestResponse resource = response;
            var content = resource.Content;
            PopulateList ();
        });
```

You must use a RestResponse.

If it does not work, maybe it comes from your query or bad serialization.